# How to extend the background of a CSS-arrow to the whole page width?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a downward-pointing arrow (.down) with CSS as a decorative element between the sections of a one-page site.

The problem is that the background-color of the .down-class is not spanning the whole width of the page:

[image]

This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
... </div>

<!-- About End-->


<div id="seperator"></div>

<div class="down"></div>


<!-- Portfolio -->

<div class="container-portfolio"> ... </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#seperator {
    background: #34495E;
    height: 10px;
    left: 0; right: 0;
}

.down {
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border-left: 20px solid transparent;
   border-right: 20px solid transparent;
   border-top: 20px solid #34495E;
   margin:  0 auto;
   background: #16A085;
   background-size: 100%;
 }
```

I already tried to modify the background-size property of the .down-class, unfortunately without success. I would appreciate your advice on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the background on the `.down` div and giving it 100% width, and then creating the 'arrow' as an `:after` pseudo-element.

```
#seperator {
  background: #34495E;
  height: 10px;
  left: 0; right: 0;
}

.down {
  width: 100%;
  background: #16A085;
}

.down:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #34495E;
}
```

Like this:

http://jsbin.com/APIyEbIp/1/edit

Comment: This works perfect. Thank you very much. Is there a way to add an additional, smaller arrow in the color of the upper container resembling this style: http://cssarrowplease.com/ ?

Comment: You can create another arrow using the `:before` pseudo-element if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to wrap another background class. Like this:

```
#seperator {
    background: #34495E;
    height: 10px;
    left: 0; right: 0;
}

.down {
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border-left: 20px solid transparent;
   border-right: 20px solid transparent;
   border-top: 20px solid #34495E;
   margin:  0 auto;

 }

.down_bkg {
        background: #16A085;
        background-size: 100%;
        width:100%;
    }
```

And HTML is like this:

```
<div id="seperator"></div>

<div class="down_bkg">
    <div class="down"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the down class CSS

width:100% or 
min-width: 100%

Comment: This would destroy the arrow-shape by extending the borders to the whole page width.